# Order in which filters are applied to Inbound ftp adapters in spring integration

Tags: ftp, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am using spring integration inbound channel adapter as below

```
inboundAdapter(csf).preserveTimestamp(true)//
              .remoteDirectory(feed.getRemoteDirectory())//
              .regexFilter(feed.getRegexFilter())// regex expression
              .filter(ftpRemoteFileFilter)// remote filter
              .deleteRemoteFiles(feed.getDeleteRemoteF
```

So I am using a remote filter and the out of the box regex filter . I wanted to know what is the order in which the regex filter and the remote filter are applied . From initial analysis looks like the regex filter comes first , can some one tell me the clas where this decision is made so I can be sure .

If there is no way of knowing the only other alternative will be to use the 
`CompositeFileListFilter` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you looking for is in the `FtpInboundChannelAdapterSpec` and looks like:

```
@Override
public FtpInboundChannelAdapterSpec regexFilter(String regex) {
    return filter(composeFilters(new FtpRegexPatternFileListFilter(regex)));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private CompositeFileListFilter<FTPFile> composeFilters(FileListFilter<FTPFile> fileListFilter) {
    CompositeFileListFilter<FTPFile> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilters(fileListFilter,
            new FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "ftpMessageSource"));
    return compositeFileListFilter;
}
```

So, as you see when you declare `regexFilter`, it is composed together with the `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` to the the `CompositeFileListFilter`, where `regexFilter` is definitely first. And it is first because `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` is *persistence* and that wouldn't be good to store files which might not match the regexp afterwards.

If you need some more complicated logic, you really should go `CompositeFileListFilter` way and inject it via `filter()` option only. I mean you have to combine your `regexpFilter` into the `CompositeFileListFilter` instead of `regexFilter()`.

Note: after moving Java DSL into Core in `5.0`, the `.filter()` option looks like:

```
public S filter(FileListFilter<F> filter) {
    this.synchronizer.setFilter(filter);
    return _this();
}
```

It overrides any previously provided filters, including `regexp`. That is done to avoid confusing with the chain of `.filter()` in favor of `CompositeFileListFilter` or `ChainFileListFilter` configured externally.

Comment: ok sounds good so better option will be to chuck the regexFilter and use CompositeFileListFilter Filter to be future proof .